# Hibernate: pros & cons of association mapping without foreginkey

Tags: hibernate

I ran in to requirement where I have two tables, Order and Item which has "1 to many" association between Order --> Item. However, there is no foreign key.

Just wondering if the Pojo can be designed to have an association relation as per the ORM design principles.

What are the pros and cons apart from the fact that application middle tier will have to ensure the association.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Hibernate doesn't care about foreign keys. When you add them to your mapping or annotation, it is only used for generating DDL, if you ask Hibernate to generate DDL for you instead of doing it manually. I haven't been able to substantiate this though with the documentation. Again, in my experience, I haven't seen that Hibernate makes use of foreign keys.

I see no issues aside from the one you mention. It is a biggie though and should be avoided if at all possible.

Regarding the object world versus the relational world, consider what Christian Bauer and Gavin King say in "Java Persistence with Hibernate"

> Object-oriented languages represent associations using object
>   references; but in the relational world, an association is represented
>   as a foreign key column, with copies of key values (and a constraint
>   to guarantee integrity). There are substantial differences between
>   the two representations...
>
> Object references are inherently directional; the association is from
>   one object to the other. They’re pointers...
>
> On the other hand, foreign key associations aren’t by nature
>   directional. Navigation has no meaning for a relational data model
>   because you can create arbitrary data associations with table joins
>   and projection. The challenge is to bridge a completely open data
>   model, which is independent of the application that works with the
>   data, to an application-dependent navigational model, a constrained
>   view of the associations needed by this particular application.

So, what I get from that, is that there is already a disconnect. So Hibernate not using a foreign key definition makes sense to me.

Comment: Did this help? Can I be of further assistance?